# Asterisk redirect incoming call to last number that called it

Tags: asterisk

I would like to know how to redirect an incoming call to the extension that called it first in Asterisk. I have not found a way to do it, and I haven't found any Asterisk variable that contain a value for the call history of a incoming call.